# SQL statement, get query RSQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rsqlite

I am new to SQL and having trouble with RSQLite.

Here is an example of my table:

```
counts    Month
0         June
4         June
2         March
5         July
3         July
```

I would like to create a search query using dbGetQuery that will count up the number of counts for each month from my `totals` table. Im looking for output that looks like this:

```
counts    Month
4         June
2         March
8         July
```

So far I have this but is incorrect. `dbGetQuery(conn=db, "SELECT Count(counts) FROM totals group by [Month]")`

Comment: If you want Months in the output you need to add it to the select list ... (And probably SUM() not COUNT())

Comment: What is the output and how is it incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your desired output seems that you don't want to count the `counts` but to sum them. As stated by @AlexK, you also need `Month` in your select to have it displayed along with the sum result

```
dbGetQuery(conn=db, "SELECT [Month], sum(counts) as counts FROM totals group by [Month]")
```